# Call AudioUnitRender outside of the render call back method

Tags: ios, audiounit

Like the sample project [MixerHost](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MixerHost/Introduction/Intro.html),I want to write the mixed output stream to a file instead of to the speakers.So I used kAudioUnitSubType_GenericOutput and call:

```
CheckError(AudioUnitInitialize(mixerUnit), "AudioUnitInitialize mixerUnit");
CheckError(AudioUnitInitialize(ioUnit), "AudioUnitInitialize iOUnit");
CheckError(AudioOutputUnitStart(ioUnit), "AudioOutputUnitStart iOUnit");

AudioUnitRenderActionFlags ioActionFlags = 0;
AudioTimeStamp inTimeStamp;
memset(&inTimeStamp, 0, sizeof(AudioTimeStamp));
inTimeStamp.mFlags = kAudioTimeStampSampleTimeValid;
UInt32 inOutputBusNumber = 0;
UInt32 inNumberFrames = 100;
AudioBuffer buffer;
buffer.mNumberChannels = 2;
buffer.mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames*2;
buffer.mData = malloc(inNumberFrames*2);
AudioBufferList ioData;
ioData.mNumberBuffers = 1;
ioData.mBuffers[0] = buffer;
CheckError(AudioUnitRender(ioUnit,
                           &ioActionFlags,
                           &inTimeStamp,
                           inOutputBusNumber,
                           inNumberFrames,
                           &ioData),
           "AudioUnitRender");
```

Error: AudioUnitRender (-50),Please tell me the correct way to call AudioUnitRender()

iluvcapra is right,I changed and it works:

```
AudioUnitRenderActionFlags flags = 0;
AudioTimeStamp inTimeStamp;
memset(&inTimeStamp, 0, sizeof(AudioTimeStamp));
inTimeStamp.mFlags = kAudioTimeStampSampleTimeValid;
UInt32 busNumber = 0;
UInt32 numberFrames = 100;

int channelCount = 2;
AudioBufferList *bufferList = (AudioBufferList*)malloc(sizeof(AudioBufferList)+sizeof(AudioBuffer)*(channelCount-1));
bufferList->mNumberBuffers = channelCount;
for (int i=0; i<channelCount; i++) {
    AudioBuffer buffer = {0};
    buffer.mNumberChannels = 1;
    buffer.mDataByteSize = numberFrames*sizeof(AudioUnitSampleType);
    buffer.mData = calloc(numberFrames, sizeof(AudioUnitSampleType));

    bufferList->mBuffers[i] = buffer;

}
CheckError(AudioUnitRender(ioUnit,
                           &flags,
                           &inTimeStamp,
                           busNumber,
                           numberFrames,
                           bufferList),
           "AudioUnitRender ioUnit");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things, though without seeing more I can't say if this is all that's wrong:

- Your sample time isn't valid, you have to increment this for every loop of the rendition.
- Your AudioBuffer and AudioBufferList aren't being set up properly, the mixer's output data format generally splits channels into separate `AudioBuffer`s instead of interleaving. Either way you're not allocating enough space, you're `malloc`ing when you should be `calloc`ing, and you're allocating in sample-sized objects, not byte-sized ones.

Your `AudioBufferList` allocation should look more like this (after MixerHost's):

```
AudioBufferList *ioData = (AudioBufferList *) malloc (
        sizeof (AudioBufferList) + sizeof (AudioBuffer) * (channelCount - 1)
    );


    ioData->mNumberBuffers = channelCount;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < channelCount; i++) {
        ioData->mBuffers[i] = {0};
        ioData->mBuffers[i].mNumberChannels  = 1;
        ioData->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize = BUFFER_SIZE_IN_SAMPLES * 
             sizeof (AudioUnitSampleType);
        ioData->mBuffers[i].mData = calloc(BUFFER_SIZE_IN_SAMPLES, 
             sizeof(AudioUnitSampleType);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! could you tell me where is the proper place to call AudioUnitRender repeatedly,should i call it in a new thread?

Comment: You can call it here or from a new thread, just never call Render from two different threads.  You might also consider just wrapping this up in an AUGraph and letting it do all the backgrounding for you; you can get the output of an AUGraph from *it's* render callback.

Comment: I'm considering use AUGraph, did you mean use AUGraphAddRenderNotify to get the output of an AUGraph? and where to first call Render, because nothing happens after i called AUGraphStart.